# $\log[E(y|x)]$ vs $E[\log(y)|x)]$

Tags: econometrics, conditional-expectation, intuition, elasticity

I have these two equations for elasticity:
$$\frac {∂\log[\hat E(y|\mathbf X)]}{∂\log(\mathbf X_j)}   $$
&
$$\frac {∂[\hat E(\log(y)|\mathbf X)]}{∂\log(\mathbf X_j)}   $$

I understand that if my disturbance term u is independent of my explanatory variables $\mathbf X$ then they are the same, though I'm not entirely clear as to why or the intuition behind it. Any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these the true conditional expectations, or estimated conditional expectations?

Comment: Sorry should have made clear, they are estimations, currently studying regression.

Comment: It would be best to state your model fully. Sometimes, functional forms matter. For example is this linear regression? Is this linear regression? But what kind of "linear" is it? What are the transformations involved? etc.

Comment: What is $u$?  I don't see it in your equations.

Comment: I have no specific model am afraid. Am just studying the theory of when specific methodologies can be applied to calculate elasticities of different variables in my estimations. My text informs me the first equation can be applied across any functional form, so I imagine that implies the second isn't as versatile.

Comment: @Neil G, the above conditional expectations are estimations related to regression analysis, so in their equation form would look something like log(y) = b0 + b1 log (x1) + b2x2 + u where b* are my coefficients and x* are my explanatory variables.

Comment: @Nik-D How is $u$ different from $b_0$?  And why are you doing regressing with a linear combination of $\log x_1$ and  $x_2$?